# Windows batch loop saving results into a file line by line

Tags: windows, batch-file, imagemagick

I run a command on each file within a folder and I would like to write the result line by line in a text file

```
for %r in (*) do (magick identify -format "%f, %w, %h" %r >> out.txt)
```

(it returns the image name and its size)

Which gives:

> `1048.tif, 3175, 2802,1049.tif, 3175, 2802...`

I would like something like

```
> 1048.tif, 3175, 2802
> 1049.tif, 3175, 2802...
```

I tried with echo before magick identify but it writes the command and not the result

Comment: I cannot believe that this code works in a batch file since you did not double the `%`-signs; so you are executing it in a Windows Command Prompt window (`cmd.exe`), right?

Comment: `... do (magick identify -format "%f, %w, %h" %r &echo/ >> out.txt)`

Comment: @Stephan, I'm afraid this would only output a line-break plus a space to the file `out.txt`...

Comment: @aschipfl: ok, `do (... &echo/)>>out.txt` then. But the accepted solution is far better anyhow (generating the correct data instead of post-processing to correct it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ImageMagick you can try putting a "\n" in your format string...

```
... -format "%f, %w, %h\n" ...
```

That will insert a line break after the height.